# SQL Find/Count similar duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to to do a count on all records that are similar.
Eg.

I have 2 records 1 is 1A Smith St and the other is 1 Smith St.
So this data needs to be returned/counted as 1.

Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output you expect here?  Can you add more sample data?

Comment: The ones in yellow would need to be counted so the above data would have  a count of 2. The non highlighted address can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting those where the (street, number) combination isn't unique.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT Street, Number
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Street, Number
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS NUMBER, Suffix, Street FROM TableName GROUP BY Suffix, Street
```